# PHP 7.1 - Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php

Just built a new server with PHP 7.1.10. Twice now, I have received this error when it's not an actual error (I don't think). Restarting apache fixes it. The file that the function is in, is called with include_once. This totally works locally and on the old php 5.6 server. It does work on 7.1... until something happens.

Like I said, I restart apache, and everything works like normal. I am using the webtactic php-71w.

The other thing is, the function it can't redeclare is the last function in the file. If I delete that function, it'll say it can't redeclare the next last function.

So is this a bug in php? A bug in the webtatic php package? Something else?

Comment: Any idea what causes the event? Does it happen across scripts with the same include?

Comment: What is "webtactic php-71w"?

Comment: https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/

Comment: @JayBlanchard No idea what causes it. I don't believe it happens across scripts but I can do some more testing there.

Comment: Are there other errors in the log just prior to this error?

Comment: Sounds bug-report worthy (test wo/ and w/ Opcache + [_consistency+revalidate_](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php) flags e.g.), and warrants `if (function_exists(...))` masking for now.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention @mario, I did try that. I did a !function_exists{} and it still tried to recreate the function. Maybe I will try disabling opcache because it makes sense that it's some sort of caching issue.